# Load properties of list item dynamically in CSOM

Tags: development, sharepoint-server, client-object-model

I have a situation where I need to load items from the list and which columns to be loaded cannot be hardcoded, as it will be decided on user input.

I have the following code:

```
ocamlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><RowLimit>1</RowLimit><Query>" + camlQuery + "</Query>" +
    "<ViewFields>" +
    propertiesNames +
    "</ViewFields></View>";
ListItemCollection oListItemColl = oList.GetItems(ocamlQuery);
context.Load(oListItemColl,oList.Fields=>oList.Fields);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

When I am looping through the list item collection and try to access the value, I receive the error message:

> The property or field has not been initialized.

How can I load fields dynamically depending on prior user input?

Comment: Is the extra dot at the end `oList.Fields.` a typo? `context.Load(oListItemColl,oList.Fields=>oList.Fields.);`

Answer (score 4):

At least two options are available then you need to specify explicitly which field values to retrieve.

### Using CAML query using `ViewFields` attribute

For example, [CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ee543831.aspx)

```
public static CamlQuery CreateAllItemsQuery(
    int rowLimit,
    params string[] viewFields
)
```

accepts `viewFields` parameter to specify which field values to retrieve

Below is provided custom version for `CreateAllItemsQuery` method:

```
public static CamlQuery CreateAllItemsQuery(int rowLimit, params string[] viewFields)
{
     if (rowLimit <= 0)
         throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("rowLimit");
     if (viewFields == null)
         throw new ArgumentNullException("viewFields");
     var camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
     var output = new StringBuilder();
     var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(output, new XmlWriterSettings()
     {
         OmitXmlDeclaration = true
     });
     xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("View");
     if (viewFields.Length > 0)
     {
         xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("ViewFields");
         foreach (string str in viewFields)
         {
              if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
              {
                  xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("FieldRef");
                  xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Name", str);
                  xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
              }
         }
         xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
     }
     xmlWriter.WriteElementString("RowLimit", rowLimit.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
     xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
     xmlWriter.Close();
     camlQuery.ViewXml = output.ToString();
     return camlQuery;
}
```

Usage

```
//Load and print Managed metadata column named "Document Type"
var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
var items = list.GetItems(CreateAllItemsQuery(8, new[] { "DocumentType" }));
context.Load(items);
context.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (var item in items)
{
     var docTypeVal = item["DocumentType"] as TaxonomyFieldValue;
     Console.WriteLine(docTypeVal.Label);
}
```

### Using ClientContext.Load method

[ClientRuntimeContext.Load method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj171831%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

```
public void Load<T>(
    T clientObject,
    params Expression<Func>[] retrievals
)
where T : ClientObject
```

accepts `retrievals` parameter to specify which field values to retrieve

Usage

```
 var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
 var items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
 context.Load(items, ic => ic.Include(i => i["DocumentType"]));
 context.ExecuteQuery();
 foreach (var item in items)
 {
     var docTypeVal = item["DocumentType"] as TaxonomyFieldValue;
     Console.WriteLine(docTypeVal.Label);
 }
```