# Sharepoint 2013 Return List Columns in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the below code which is finding a List on a Page and alerting the "Title" of each item in the list. Within the list I have a number of columns such as "Description" "Priority" etc, how do I return these column values?

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

function getItemsFromView(listTitle, viewTitle) {
        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
        var view = list.get_views().getByTitle(viewTitle);
        context.load(view);
        context.executeQueryAsync(
        function (sender, args) { getItemsFromList(listTitle, "<View><Query>" + view.get_viewQuery() + "</Query></View>") },
        function (sender, args) { alert("error: " + args.get_message()); }
        );
    }
function getItemsFromList(listTitle, queryText) {
        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
        var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
        query.set_viewXml(queryText);
        var items = list.getItems(query);
        context.load(items);
        context.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {
            var listEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
            var i = 0;
            while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                console.log(listEnumerator.get_current().get_item('Title'));
                alert(listEnumerator.get_current().get_item('Title'));
                i++;
            }
            //alert("items retrieved: " + i);          
        },
        function (sender, args) { alert("error in inner request: " + args.get_message()); }
        );
    }

function getItems() {
    getItemsFromView("Test List", "");
 }

 SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getItems);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the columns as below:

```
context.load(items,'Include(Title,Description,Priority)'); //specify internal names of columns in comma separated format
```

To check the value, logs value to console:

```
console.log(listEnumerator.get_current().get_item('Description'));

console.log(listEnumerator.get_current().get_item('Priority'));
```

So, you overall code would look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

function getItemsFromView(listTitle, viewTitle) {
        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
        var view = list.get_views().getByTitle(viewTitle);
        context.load(view);
        context.executeQueryAsync(
        function (sender, args) { getItemsFromList(listTitle, "<View><Query>" + view.get_viewQuery() + "</Query></View>") },
        function (sender, args) { alert("error: " + args.get_message()); }
        );
    }
function getItemsFromList(listTitle, queryText) {
        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
        var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
        query.set_viewXml(queryText);
        var items = list.getItems(query);
        context.load(items,'Include(Title,Description,Priority)');
        context.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {
            var listEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
            var i = 0;
            while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                console.log(listEnumerator.get_current().get_item('Title'));

                alert(listEnumerator.get_current().get_item('Title'));

                console.log(listEnumerator.get_current().get_item('Description'));

                console.log(listEnumerator.get_current().get_item('Priority'));

                i++;
            }
            //alert("items retrieved: " + i);          
        },
        function (sender, args) { alert("error in inner request: " + args.get_message()); }
        );
    }

function getItems() {
    getItemsFromView("Test List", "");
 }

 SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getItems);

</script>
```

Reference - [Include custom fields in context.load](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/128653/8068)

Comment: Thanks, I am now getting the error: "error in inner request: Column 'Description' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user"

Comment: check if `Description` column exists in the list and then use the internal column name. In case of tasks list, it is `Body`, so you can replace `Description` with `Body`

Comment: Ah yes it needed the internal column name - helpfully labelled "cp5g"

Comment: The "cp5g" Internal names are created if you add Fields using the Modern Experiences (where you only enter the Field DisplayName) still best practice is to add Fields in the List settings, where your first entered name will become the Internal Name (so you enter them without special characters and spaces, then after saving open the edit Field once more and set the correct DisplayName)... It was a pain... it still is a pain with Modern Experiences

Comment: I have another Question - This code works for returning lists on the current SharePoint page, I want to retrieve list items from a list in a sub-site, whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Replace  with `var context = new SP.ClientContext('server relative url of the web');`

Comment: This is the full URL of the page: Do I use this? "http://sharepoint/StrategicProjectOffice/Lists/Project%20Tasks%20%20Test%203%20List/AllItems.aspx"

Comment: Use it as `var context = new SP.ClientContext('/StrategicProjectOffice')`

Comment: Cool ! Could you mark it as answer?

Comment: I've posted a separate question as I want to return data from multiple lists where the title starts with "Test - " which i think is a lot more complex