# Update another field with an id of a lookup column

Tags: csom, lookup-column, updatelistitems, update, spfieldlookupvalue

I have a list with around 1000 columns and I need to be a able to prepopulate another field with a lookupid of another lookup field on the same list

I am getting error when I use:

```
var LookUpColumnId = oListItem.get_item('LookUpColumn').get_lookupId();
```

Error:

> Uncaught Error: The property or field has not been initialized. It has
>   not been requested or the request has not been executed.

See snippet below:

```
function onUpdateSucceeded() {

    var itemEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
    while (itemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var item = itemEnumerator.get_current();
        // You now have the item you were looking for!
        //console.log(item.get_item("ID"));
        IDs.push(item.get_item("ID"));
    }
    console.log(IDs);

    var siteUrl = '/sites/Dev/'; 
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Test');

    var itemsToLoadForUpdate = Array(); // Holds our "current" items to update
    var totalItemsToUpdate = 900;
    var limitItemsToUpdate = 50; // Update every 90 items

    var batchUpdatesCounter = Math.ceil(totalItemsToUpdate / limitItemsToUpdate); // If you need to count the remaining batch updates
    var restItemsToUpdate = 0; // Items to update after (see below)

    for (var i = 0; i < IDs.length; i++) {
        var oListItem = oList.getItemById(IDs[i]);

        /* Newly addedd get lookup id of items*/

        //var lookupFieldValue = oListItem.get_item('LookUpColumn');
        //var lookupId = lookupFieldValue.get_lookupId();

        //console.log(LookUpColumnId);
        //alert(lookupFieldValue);

        //This works but when i set the lookupId above it doesn't i can;t even get the lookupId 
        oListItem.set_item('LookUpID', 1);

        oListItem.update();
        itemsToLoadForUpdate[i] = oListItem;

        clientContext.load(itemsToLoadForUpdate[i]);
        if (i && i % limitItemsToUpdate == 0) {
            console.log('Updating ' + limitItemsToUpdate + ' items...');
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(this.onUpdateSucceeded, this.onUpdateFailed);
            restItemsToUpdate = 0;
        }
        else { // Remaining items to update
            restItemsToUpdate = i % limitItemsToUpdate;
        }

    }

    if (restItemsToUpdate) {
        //console.log('Updating rest items...');
        console.log('Updating ' + restItemsToUpdate + ' items...');

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(this.onUpdateSucceeded, this.onUpdateFailed);
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

New Update code :-

```
 var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    //camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query></Query><RowLimit>900</RowLimit></View>');
    camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query></Query><RowLimit>900</RowLimit><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='LookUpColumn' LookupId='TRUE' /></ViewFields></View>");
    items = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
    //clientContext.load(items);    
    clientContext.load(items,'Include(LookUpColumn)');
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onUpdateSucceeded, onUpdateFailed);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to request the Property of the item with something like `clientContext.load(yourItemCollection , 'Include(LookUpColumn)')` or for a single item `clientContext.load(yourItem, 'LookUpColumn')`

Take a look at [Complete basic operations using JavaScript library code in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-javascript-library-code-in-sharepoint) and [How to include custom fields in clientContext.load](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/128650/how-to-include-custom-fields-in-clientcontext-load)

Comment: Thanks for that but i'm still getting the error after adding "clientContext.load(items,'Include(LookUpColumn)');"
 and changed the query to :- camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query></Query><RowLimit>900</RowLimit><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='LookUpColumn' LookupId='TRUE' /></ViewFields></View>");

Comment: At which line do you get the error?
Try to run the following line after loading the Column....
`<code>var lookupValue = oListItem.get_item('LookUpColumn');`

What's the result?

Comment: Thanks.On this line :- var LookUpColumnId = oListItem.get_item('LookUpColumn')

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem. Thank you.

Comment: mitti that didn't work. The issue i have is this line 
 var oListItem = oList.getItemById(IDs[i]);
How can i get the lookup field using the below when using the oListItem from the above
//var lookupFieldValue = oListItem.get_item('LookUpColumn');
//var lookupId = lookupFieldValue.get_lookupId();
Thanks

Comment: new post here https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/260554/the-property-or-field-has-not-been-initialized-when-setting-a-lookupfield-id-on